# Zip two HashMaps(or dictionaries)

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming

What would be a functional way to zip two dictionaries in Scala?

```
map1 = new HashMap("A"->1,"B"->2)
map2 = new HashMap("B"->22,"D"->4) // B is the only common key
```

`zipper(map1,map2)` should give something similar to

```
 Seq( ("A",1,0), // no A in second map, so third value is zero
      ("B",2,22),
      ("D",0,4)) // no D in first map, so second value is zero
```

If not functional, any other style is also appreciated

Comment: Haskell's Data.Map has a wonderful combinator called `unionWith` that would make this amazingly easy. It and its intersection counterpart are remarkably useful, and I regret that they're only available in Scala's `IntMap` and `LongMap` (mostly because those are translated from Haskell, I expect).

Comment: @copumpkin: Haskell is amazing! I will check out unionWith.I just checked IntMap and it is now superceded by HashMap from 2.8 on

Comment: It isn't really superseded by `HashMap`, despite what the documentation comment suggests. They're different structures, and `IntMap` has different properties. Sometimes you really don't want the hashing function in there, particularly when you want to maintain the ordering of data. `IntMap` could mostly implement `SortedMap` but I don't think it does right now. One gotcha is that it follows an "unsigned" ordering, but it's not hard to make it behave like a signed one if that's what you need.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
def zipper(map1: Map[String, Int], map2: Map[String, Int]) = {
  for(key <- map1.keys ++ map2.keys)
    yield (key, map1.getOrElse(key, 0), map2.getOrElse(key, 0))
}


scala> val map1 = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap("A" -> 1, "B" -> 2)
map1: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map(A -> 1, B -> 2)

scala> val map2 = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap("B" -> 22, "D" -> 4)
map2: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map(B -> 22, D -> 4)

scala> :load Zipper.scala
Loading Zipper.scala...
zipper: (map1: Map[String,Int], map2: Map[String,Int])Iterable[(String, Int, Int)]

scala> zipper(map1, map2)
res1: Iterable[(String, Int, Int)] = Set((A,1,0), (B,2,22), (D,0,4))
```

Note using `get` is probably preferable to `getOrElse` in this case. `None` is used to specify that a value does not exist instead of using `0`.

Comment: Is there some way to get the 'zero' of  a type parameter? Zipper could be made generic apart from those pesky '0's

Comment: I'm not sure that'd be the right direction to generalize, but you could look at `Monoid` which has an (associative) operation and a zero. A zero on its own wouldn't make much sense, since what makes it a zero is how it interacts with other things. As I suggested in my other comment, I think `unionWith[A,B](x: Map[A,B], y: Map[A,B])(f: (B, B) => B): Map[A, B]` is the ideal approach here. The combining function is only used when there is overlap so you don't even need a notion of a zero. More general: `unionWith[K,A,B,C])(x: Map[K,A], y: Map[K,B])(l: A => C, r: B => C, b: (A,B) => C): Map[K,C]`.

Comment: Note that the more general one is only needed if you want to "remember" that one of the two sides was missing, and is effectively equivalent to using `mapValues` on both inputs and throwing them into `Either` before calling the less general `unionWith`. To go a little farther off the deep end, if you think of a `Map` as just an efficient datastructure to represent `K => Option[V]`, then the various options are just variations on the essence of the `K => _` monad. I say the essence because `Map` doesn't quite work as a `Monad`/`Applicative`, but if you drop the `return`/`pure` it does.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Brian's answer, this can be used to enhance the map class by way of implicit methods:

```
implicit class MapUtils[K, +V](map: collection.Map[K, V]) {
  def zipAllByKey[B >: V, C >: V](that: collection.Map[K, C], thisElem: B, thatElem: C): Iterable[(K, B, C)] =
  for (key <- map.keys ++ that.keys)
    yield (key, map.getOrElse(key, thisElem), that.getOrElse(key, thatElem))
}
```

The naming and API are similar to the sequence `zipAll`.